# Dockerfile to install python3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, docker

As per the requirements i have to install python3 on top of amazoncorreto image so that python codes can be ran on container.

I have written below dockerfile for this

```
FROM amazoncorretto
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.4

ARG APPUSER=app

RUN yum -y update &&\
    yum install -y shadow-utils findutils gcc sqlite-devel zlib-devel \
                   bzip2-devel openssl-devel readline-devel libffi-devel && \
    groupadd ${APPUSER} && useradd ${APPUSER} -g ${APPUSER} && \
    cd /usr/local/src && \
    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar -xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && make && make altinstall && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/src/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}* && \
    yum remove -y shadow-utils audit-libs libcap-ng && yum -y autoremove && \
    yum clean all
```

after image is created i tried to run a container from that image

```
docker run -it image-name /bin/bash
python3.6.4 -V
command not found
python --version
2.7
```

I am not able to figure out why python is not getting installed here.

Also its taking very long time to build image.Below are the messages

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/local/src/Python-3.6.4'
: # FIXME: can't run for a cross build
./python -m test.regrtest --pgo || true
Run tests sequentially
0:00:00 load avg: 0.97 [  1/406] test_grammar
0:00:00 load avg: 0.97 [  2/406] test_opcodes
0:00:00 load avg: 0.97 [  3/406] test_dict
0:00:01 load avg: 0.97 [  4/40
```

Comment: I get an error when building that Dockerfile; are you sure that's the Dockerfile you are using?

Answer (score 1):

You have to also install  `tar gzip gcc make` using `yum` as `amazoncorretto` does not come with these packages. They are required to compile python.

```
FROM amazoncorretto
ARG PYTHON_VERSION=3.6.4

ARG APPUSER=app

RUN yum -y update &&\
    yum install -y shadow-utils findutils gcc sqlite-devel zlib-devel \
                   bzip2-devel openssl-devel readline-devel libffi-devel tar gzip gcc make && \
    groupadd ${APPUSER} && useradd ${APPUSER} -g ${APPUSER} && \
    cd /usr/local/src && \
    curl -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/${PYTHON_VERSION}/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    tar -xzf Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}.tgz && \
    cd Python-${PYTHON_VERSION} && \
    ./configure --enable-optimizations && make && make altinstall && \
    rm -rf /usr/local/src/Python-${PYTHON_VERSION}* && \
    yum remove -y shadow-utils audit-libs libcap-ng && yum -y autoremove && \
    yum clean all
```

Comment: I tried with above dockerfile but still getting same issue                                                 ```bash-4.2# python --version
Python 2.7.18
bash-4.2# python3.6.4 -V
bash: python3.6.4: command not found ```